# #define confusion with {} and declaration

Tags: c++

I recently got a C++ program for my school test.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#define convert(p,q) p+2*q

void main()
{
int a,b,result;
cin>>a>>b;
result=convert(a,b);
cout<<result;
}
```

This works correctly.

When I put p+2*q in {}, it gives me the error : 
"Expression syntax in function main()"

Now when I declare result just before output, like this:

int result=convert(a,b);

It works. Why and why not?

Comment: That's not the problem tho why does this happen. The problem is with the {}.

Comment: Oh, right - can you post the actual code that causes problems?

Comment: Show a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: `main` must return `int`. There is no standard header `iostream.h`. `cin` and `cout` are defined in the `std` namespace, not the global one. Are you using non-standard C++ version? You should mention that in the question.

Comment: The second version works for it is interpreted as initialization. You're using an old compiler. There are many modern free compilers.

Comment: I smell Turbo C++ 3.0 from 1990. Given that the first formal C++ standard was released in 1998, you need extensive incompetence to hand out TC++ to your C++ students in the year 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using macros if you have trouble understanding what the compiler complains about. This is what your code looks like when the macro is expanded, when you put the extra {}

```
result={a+2*b}
```

And this is what it looks like with the declaration on the same line

```
int result={a+2*b}
```

Before the C++11 standard, the former is a syntax error. Since C++11, it is [copy-list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) of a temporary (see the syntax labeled (10) ).

The latter is [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: the first line is fine in C++11?

Comment: @tobi303 yes, I added a mention of what the syntax means since C++11.